# TFlowPanel. Adding controls at run-time

Tags: delphi, controls, flowpanel

Does anybody know how to add controls, say a TImage, to a TFlowPanel at runtime?

Regards, Pieter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add any control to a parent control:

```
MyControl := TMyControl.Create(MyForm); // Form is the owner
MyControl.Parent := ParentControl;      // Parent control is the parent
```

You can set other properties too if you like.

Answer (score 8):

There is just a slight difference with a normal container, you can set the order of the child controls.

```
OldIndex:= FlowPanel.GetControlIndex( MyControl );     
FlowPanel.SetControlIndex( MyControl, OldIndex + 1 );
```